# add a suffix when col names are similar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am merging two dataframes and both of them have a col called "man". After the join, one col is called "man_x" and the second is called "man_y". Is it possible to append the table name or any other string instead of x, y when column names are the same?

```
df_merged = df['first'].merge(df['second'], 
                                        left_on=['posnr'],
                                        right_on=['fk_eakopf_posnr'],
                                        how='inner')
```

After this, If I add another table to this `df_merged`, the third `man` col will remain `man`. So it's a bit hard to debug, which is why I would like to add proper suffixes everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `suffixes=` parameter of [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to specify your desired suffixes.

> **suffixes**  list-like, default is (“_x”, “_y”)
>
> A length-2 sequence where
> each element is optionally a string indicating the suffix to add to
> overlapping column names in left and right respectively. Pass a value
> of None instead of a string to indicate that the column name from left
> or right should be left as-is, with no suffix. At least one of the
> values must not be None.

The default is `suffixes=('_x', '_y')`

You can specify e.g. `suffixes=('_df1', '_df2')` for merging  2 dataframes `df1` and `df2` to know the source dataframes.